# Inaccurate flow rate measurements of an engine diesel fuel due to change of its viscosity

Tags: fluid-mechanics, measurements, sensors, diesel, fuel

I am measuring the volumetric flow rate of a diesel fuel using "Turbines" [flow meter](https://www.gilsoneng.com/WebCat6/pdf/TI_datasheet_TM_Series.pdf), both in the supply and return fuel lines of an industrial diesel engine ([Caterpillar 3512B](https://www.cat.com/en_US/products/new/power-systems/industrial/industrial-diesel-engines/18398034.html) – coupled with a generator for power production), in an attempt to measure the total fuel consumption by the engine. However, the fuel temperature in the return line is higher than the fuel temperature in the supply line, thus, the viscosity of the return fuel is lower than the viscosity of the supply fuel. Due to this change in fuel viscosity, I obtain erroneous flow rate measurements.

Therefore, I was wondering if there is a way to compensate for the temperature or viscosity change of the diesel fuel in order to obtain accurate volumetric flow rate measurements.

Thank you for any idea you could provide.

Comment: So measure the viscosity over the temperature range then re-compute the results. And did this with manometers used to measure airflow which needed temperature compensation.

Comment: you will need temperature sensors and maybe even a calibration rig to measure viscosity.  depending on how quickly your temperature changes at a given point and how much you care about the data under those conditions you may wish to model in time constants of temperature sensors.  Depending on differences between temperature and flow measurement points, you may need to model that too.

Comment: You should be able to plug into the ECM to see fuel rate using Caterpillar's ET (Electronic Technician) software.  Your local Cat distributor should be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks, @ToddTakala.